# Android setup ACRA to get application bugs and crashes doesnt work

Tags: android, acra

this below code are my simple setup ACRA to get craches and my application bugs, but the setup acra doesnt send any report

```
@ReportsCrashes(
        /*LOCALHOST*/
        formUri = "http://192.168.1.35/acra.php/acra.php",
        customReportContent = {ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE, ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME, ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, ReportField.PHONE_MODEL, ReportField.CUSTOM_DATA, ReportField.STACK_TRACE, ReportField.LOGCAT},
        mode = ReportingInteractionMode.DIALOG)

public class EpayApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ACRA.init(this);
    }
}
```

Localhost php file:

```
<?php
    // Outputs all POST parameters to a text file. The file name is the date_time of the report reception
    $fileName = date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').'.txt';
    $file = fopen($fileName,'w') or die('Could not create report file: ' . $fileName);
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $reportLine = $key." = ".$value."\n";
        fwrite($file, $reportLine) or die ('Could not write to report file ' . $reportLine);
    }
    fclose($file);
?>
```

entering `http://192.168.1.35/acra.php/acra.php` can be create empty file and it doesnt have any problem to get report, my acra version is `4.9.0`

my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:name=".AppApplication"
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `android:name` attribute should be same as the Application class name that you've created. It's different in your case.

Change this

```
android:name=".AppApplication"
```

to

```
android:name=".EpayApplication"
```